# Do multiple seperate SPF records work?

Tags: office365, spf

Hi I am on Office365 and using it for DNS which doesn't allow you to modify the default SPF record, which basically contains the office365 mail servers.

I need to add an additional mail server to my SPF record to allow me to additionally send mail from another server.

My question is will my email still function correctly if I have two SPF records (which it allows me to do) IE:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
v=spf1 include:myother.server.com -all
```

Rather than the normal:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:myother.server.com -all
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unfortunately, you may only publish a single SPF record. Multiple records will cause the SPF evaluation to fail with "permerror" (see RFC 7208, Section 4.5.).